# Как у элемента с абсолютным позиционированием сделать margin-bottom?

Tags: html, css

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.main {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 100px; /* Не работает */
}
.main > div {
  padding: 2px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Какого поведения и от кого ты вообще ожидаешь? Вот есть элемент... Ему добавили отступ снизу... Что ты собираешься этим сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Просто - bottom: 50px;
А также left, right, top.